# How to use a dynamically chosen class in a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I'm fairly sure that's a useless title... sorry.

I want to be able to pass in a Class to a method, and then use that class. Here's an easy, working, example:

```
def my_method(klass)
  klass.new
end
```

Using that:

```
>> my_method(Product)
=> #<Product id:nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, price: nil>
>> my_method(Order)
=> #<Order id:nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, total_value: nil>
```

What *doesn't* work is trying to use the `klass` variable on a module:

```
>> ShopifyAPI::klass.first
=> NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for ShopifyAPI:Module
```

Am I attempting an impossible task? Can anyone shed some light on this?

Cheers

Comment: Why do you think there should be a klass method on the class you are using?  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @obrok I don't think there should be a class method, what I'm hoping is that the class variable is substituted into the module so that `ShopifyAPI::klass` is `ShopifyAPI::Product` when `klass == Product` and is `ShopifyAPI::Order` when `klass == Order`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, I don't think this is *impossible*.

Surely, there is no `klass` method defined for modules <- this is true because `ShopifyAPI.methods.include? "klass" # => false`

However, classes are constants in modules. And modules have a `constants` method that you may use to *retrieve* classes. The problem with this is method is that is also retrieves constants in the modules that are not classes.

I came up with this workaround for your problem

```
# get all the classes in the module
klasses = ShopifyAPI.constants.select do |klass|
    ShopifyAPI.const_get(klass).class == Class
end

# get the first class in that list
klasses.first
```

Comment: Your answer led me to the solution I was looking for! What I wanted was `ShopifyAPI.const_get(klass.to_s)`, and klass can be `Product` or `Order` etc. 

Not really sure what your solution itself was supposed to do, as getting an array of ShopifyAPI module's class name strings wasn't too helpful. I needed the class itself, so I can call methods on it. But thanks none the less!

Comment: The block in my solution returns the array `["Product", "Order"]` assuming `Product` and `Order` are classes specified in the `ShopifyAPI` module.

I was working from outside the function to get all the classes in the module before picking the first one (:

Your solution is more concise and precise

Answer (score 0):

you could also use module_eval:

```
ShopifyAPI.module_eval {klass}.first
```

Hope I got your question right :)

```
irb(main):001:0> module ShopifyAPI
irb(main):002:1> class Something
irb(main):003:2> end
irb(main):004:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> klass = ShopifyAPI::Something
=> ShopifyAPI::Something
irb(main):006:0> ShopifyAPI::klass
NoMethodError: undefined method `klass' for ShopifyAPI:Module
        from (irb):6
        from C:/Ruby192/bin/irb:12:in `<main>
irb(main):007:0> ShopifyAPI.module_eval {klass}
=> ShopifyAPI::Something
irb(main):008:0>
```